# Hit the Bulls Eye with T in the Center

Tags: word, wordplay, no-computers

There are 3 Rings with “T” in the center. In each ring, letters are distinctly different - 16 in the outer, 8 in the middle, 4 in the inner rings.

Hit the Bulls Eye by making sixteen different four letter words ending in “T”.

As an example, 2 are filled... $UNIT$, $KNIT$.
Complete the rest.

[image]

Comment: so letters in outer ring can repeat in inner ring, right?

Comment: Yes..they have to be different within each ring.

Comment: Is it in Modern English or Old English or both?

Comment: This is a really good game, by the way. Did you make this yourself? :D

Comment: Yes..there are different types of this genre by varying the shape..hope to introduce them in future on different topics like chemistry, materials..

Comment: But... but... the number of fields doubles each right, except for the first time, it quadruples! (From 1 to 4.) You're missing the ring with two segments! ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Edit:

The words in NNW are

> **LINT** and **PINT**

and not

> LENT and PENT

since we already use

> E

---

These are the answers going anti-clockwise:

> [image: Answers to the Puzzle]

> **B, G** - Gait, Bait (A, I) 
>  **L, P** - Lent, Pent (E, N) 
>  **A, R** - Aunt, Runt (U, N) 
>  **S, F** - Slat, Flat (L, A) 
>  **C, W** - Chat, What (H, A) 
>  **Z, N** - Zest, Nest (E, S) 
>  **M, H** - Mast, Hast $\qquad$ INENDED SOLUTION: Most, Host (found by @[OmegaKrypton](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51131/omega-krypton))

Also, something extra:

> The middle word is "stain" or "saint" (as an anagram) :)

Comment: What does Hast mean?

Comment: @Uvc It is the old english form of "have". It still counts as a word, but it is archaic and not part of modern english. If you hast not, you should look at the answer above ;)

Comment: Who came first? O or P?

Comment: P was first by 16 seconds, so he should get the check :) good game

Comment: @OmegaKrypton no, no, no, you got it right! I used an A at the end, which was clearly not the OP's intended solution ;)

Comment: This answer uses two "E"s in the second ring.  If I understand the rules correctly, this is not allowed.

Comment: @Pugmonkey I guess we'd need LINT and PINT instead of LENT and PENT.

Comment: @ Mr.pie you got it right..I can accept hast and your second ring conforms to what is stated as @pugmonkey has keenly observed

Comment: Or the middle word is **satin** as an anagram!

Comment: @INTERESTING Satin is a word? I didn't know that! Interesting! ;)

Comment: @MrPie Yep! It's a material, sort of like felt or silk are materials...

Answer (score 9):

Here it is, no explanation needed i think :)

> [image]

---

Note:

> As @IvánNokonoko mentioned in the comment, the NNE grid in the second layer (from outside) can also be R instead of A to form (GRIT and BRIT). Thanks!

Comment: That's exactly what I got, except the last part I did rot13(N vafgrnq bs B, ohg B vf n orggre pubvpr orpnhfr vg hfrf Zbqrea Ratyvfu). Nice one! Quicker than me :)

Comment: Rot13: Va gur gbc evtug pbeare, jurer lbh chg na N (ONVG - TNVG) V gubhtug bs na E (OEVG, TEVG) ohg V nz abg angvir fcrnxre fb V zvtug or jebat

Comment: @IvánNokonoko Good spot! thanks!